# Trigger a mass record update to "activate" workflow

Tags: trigger, workflow, field-update, automation

So I've created a workflow that update fields. This works fine but as a workflow is considered when a record is edited, only the new records, or the one edited get that field update. I would need to get all my records updated.
Is there a way to simulate a record edit in order to trigger the workflow on all records?

Thanks!
Sego

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could use the dataloader to do a mass update with nothing except the record Id, assuming they match your workflow criteria. This is enough for the record to be edited without having to do any actual field updates.

Comment: the criteria should be everytime record is edited

Answer (score 1):

in your developer console run the query. suppose your object is account.

```
List<Account> acc = [Select id from account limit 10000];
update acc
```

it will not affect your record but will trigger the WF.

Comment: you cannot update 50k records in a single transaction

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tushar's answer however if you cannot update more than 10000 records in a single DML. If you have more than 10000 record, I suggest can use data-loader to export all record Id's and blank updating them else you can use above method.